# Using JavaScript in a webpage to manage a sqlite3 database

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a web face interface to manage a local sqlite3 database.

Is it possible to use JavaScript to add, modify, and display sqlite3 database elements?

I've started to dabble in it, and it seems like it might not be possible. One thing I noticed is that the column names are different. i.e. whereas sqlite has "varchar", in JavaScript it's "text."

Also, where is the database stored? If I put my sqlite3 database file in the same directory as my html file, if I do a openDatabase() and supply the file name, will the database be opened?

Comment: Are you aware of https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/